# How to sort MongoDB record using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I was trying to create a simple web application using MongoDB and PHP. I create a table and successfully inserted data into it. Now I am trying to sort data in asc/desc and alphabetically. But here it is sorting only top 2 records.  I tried many methods but all in vain. Please help me!! Here is my code

```
<form method="post">

        <table style="width:180px" border="solid" overflow="hidden" >
          <tr>
            <th>_id</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th><button type="submit" name="notes_sort">sort</button>Title</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th> <button type="submit" name="diff_ascend">Asc</button><button type="submit" 
    name="diff_descend">Desc</button> Difficulty</th>
            <th>Related Topics</th>
            <th>Tags</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        

        <?php
            date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
            $current_date = date('d/m/Y'); 
            $options = array(
                "sort" => array("_id" => -1),
            );
            
            $data = $collection->find(array('date' => $current_date),$options);

            if(isset($_POST['diff_ascend'])){
                $options = array(
                "sort" => array("difficulty" => 1),
                );
                $data = $collection->find(array('date' => $current_date),$options);
            }

            if(isset($_POST['diff_descend'])){
                $options = array(
                "sort" => array("difficulty" => -1),
                );
                $data = $collection->find(array('date' => $current_date),$options);
            }
            
            if(isset($_POST['notes_sort'])){
                $options = array(
                "sort" => array("notes" => -1),
                );
                $data = $collection->find(array('date' => $current_date),$options);
            }
            
                        
            foreach($data as $document){
         ?> 
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $document['_id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $document['author'] ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $document["subject"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $document["title"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $document["notes"] ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $document["difficulty"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $document["rel_topic"] ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $document["tags"]["tag4"].", ".$document["tags"]["tag3"].", 
          ".$document["tags"]["tag2"].", ".$document["tags"]["tag1"]?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $document["date"] ?></td> 
               <td><a href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $document["_id"];?>' >Delete</a>  <a 
          href='update.php?id=<?php echo $document["_id"];?>' name='update'>
               Update</a></td>
               
                </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: It is the databases job to sort the results. So adapt your query.

Comment: Yeah, but here just top 2 records are getting sorted...how can I get all of them  sorted??

Comment: I think sorting by `_id` is not the right way. It is created by DB and you have no control on how it will look at the end.